# Directly mount btrfs subvolume or bind mount if already visible

Tags: mount, btrfs, bind-mount

- If `/dev/sda1` is a btrfs filesystem with subvol's `root` and `persistent`
- And I've set the default subvol to `root`
- Also, I've mounted `/dev/sda1` (again `root` is default) to `/`
- And I've mounted `/dev/sda1` subvolid=0 to `/btrfs`, so I can access all the other subvols (yes `/` now exists as a duplicate `/btrfs/root` which I find desirable so everything in here is treated as being on the same filesystem)

What differences are there between:

1. `mount /dev/sda1 -o subvol=persistent /persistent`
2. `mount --bind /btrfs/persistent /persistent`

I'm thinking along the lines of not immediately seen differences, such as being treated differently on whether going into `persistent` crosses to a different filesystem in a `cp -x` (`cp --one-file-system`).  Both options should be treated as going into a different filesystem, so there's no difference here – I just discussed this as the kind of difference that might exist, one that isn't readily apparent.

Answer (score 2):

The way you've set it up there isn't any functional difference. It's just the same as if you never created the `root subvolume` because you made it the default. It's not the way most people who are trying to take full advantage of the subvolume abstraction would do it, but it's perfectly acceptable. I personally prefer extensive separation because of the incredibly easy and powerful backups `btrfs` is known for, and without changing the default subvolume.

Nonetheless, all subvolumes are folders for most intents and purposes. The difference is you can mount them with `mount` just like a filesystem without the need for `bind` if you don't want to. As I understand it, every "normal" utility (such as the `cp` you mentioned) will treat it like a regular folder regardless of how you mount it, btrfs-specific tools excepted obviously. There might be a few exceptions, but I don't recall any in my fairly thorough testing. I invite anybody to correct me on that.

Answer (score 2):

If mount propagation is enabled (see `man mount_namespaces`) future submounts will be copied between the mounts if created using a bind mount.